# git synchronization of rebased branches

Tags: git

I recently had a [question answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165844/git-repository-setup-for-development-from-two-machines) about a multi-computer git development setup, and the solution I got there did solve my situation with the `master` branch, but not side branches based off the master.

Here's my current setup:

```
A--B--C--D  master
          \
           E--F--G--H  BUG_37
```

`BUG_37` is a branch that is developing a fix to an optional tracked bug for a feature request in the system, and will eventually be merged into the master line, but is separate for the time being. With the repository in this state, one one machine, I made some changes to the `master` branch:

```
A--B--C--D--I--J--K  master
          \
           E--F--G--H  BUG_37
```

I then rebased the `BUG_37` branch onto `master`, to ensure that it's working as an enhancement to the most current changes:

```
A--B--C--D--I--J--K  master
                   \
                    E1--F1--G1--H1  BUG_37
```

Let's say that rebase had a few conflicts that needed to be manually fixed before the rebase was final. If I push those changes to a remote repository, and now wish to pull changes down onto another development system that has the original setup still, what's the best way to do so? `git pull --rebase` will run the rebase again, and I'll have to manually go through the conflicts I went through the first time, right? And if I make a slight mistake going through the conflicts again, such that E1-H1 are slightly different in this new system, I'll get the repository even more out of sync.

How do I take a local repository in the original state and the remote repository in the third state, and have the local repository be updated to exactly match the remote repository (trashing changes E-H and moving the HEAD of `BUG_37` to the new location)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would not rebase at all on a branch which is already shared. While it results in the cleanest history, it will have changed the hashes of all the commits in `BUG_37`. So on the target machines, you will need to delete `BUG_37` entirely and pull it again. This is OK to do once or twice but not great as a regular workflow.

It will be much easier to merge `master` into `BUG_37`; then the merge commit (where you fixed the conflicts) can be pushed to other machines, and branches won't need to be deleted.

Answer (score 5):

Delete the branch, then pull both branches from the remote repository.

```
git branch -D BUG_37
git pull origin master
git pull origin BUG_37:BUG_37
```

If you don't want to delete your local BUG_37 branch before being sure that this works, pull the remote branch into another local branch:

```
git pull origin BUG_37:NEW_BUG_37
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm following the same workflow, basically switching between a laptop and desktop. I keep my main repo on the desktop and laptop clones the deskotp's repo. Eventually they get out of sync, cause I want to rebase my topic branches after I update `master`.

The simple answer, is just don't use git, instead use `rsync` to keep your repos synchronized. If you know you are the only one working on it, then this makes sense.

Well, I'm not a big fan of that solution either. So, this might be a little "cleaner". On the laptop, when pulling rebased branches from the desktop's repo:

```
git co topic
git fetch origin/topic
git reset --hard origin/topic
```

This will throw out any commits not on the desktop repo, so make sure you really want to do this.

Also, you probably can just `git pull` the laptop's `master` branch, since it should always be a fast-forward, cause you likely won't need to rebase it. I think it makes sense to rebase topic branches though, cause otherwise trying to merge it back into master at the very end is a pain.

Answer (score 3):

I have just experimented with it and using `git pull --rebase` works when pulling from a rebased branch. Without the `--rebase` flag, the commits will be duplicated, but with `--rebase` the commits are not being duplicated.